# Calculate secondary color with similar distance of existing color pair

Tags: html, css, algorithm, colors

Libraries like Bootstrap often provide pre-defined color schemes, e.g. for buttons and alerts (i.e. *success*, *info*, *warning* and *danger*). In HTML they usually consist of a `background-color` and `border-color`, the latter usually having the same tone of color, but being slightly lighter or darker. Let's say we have a button with a light green background and a dark green border.

When customizing the color scheme, I often want to replace the primary color, but maintain the distance that the primary color and its secondary color have (e.g. highlight or outline). Assuming I want to turn the button red as primary color, **how do I calculate the secondary color, so that it has the exact same distance**, that the light green and dark green had?

For example, the existing button style is:

```
background-color: #343A40;
border-color: #243030;
```

Customizing the color scheme as follows:

```
background-color: #8D33AB;
border-color: ???;
```

Currently, I translate the HEX code to RGB format and then calculate the distance of red, green and blue channel individually. Then I apply the same distances to my new primary color (i.e. adding or substracting). Is there any easier way to substitute a color, maintaining the distance of the known color pair?

Comment: I don't usually work this stuff out manually but Adobe Color Wheel (CC account not required) is awesome. Here it is https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel . I've also noticed a lot that people will use `opacity:0.5` for the border whilst using the same color for it as they used for the background to get a similar effect that you're looking for. Just ideas.

Comment: Bootstrap is using [sass's lighten/darken functions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color). You can do the same.

Comment: @bigless: Is that true for Bootstrap 3.4.1 as well, or only for Bootstrap 4.x and 5.x?

Comment: I think that v3 was using [less which has similar features](https://lesscss.org/functions/)